# DISABLE = FALSE when previous SELECT field have no value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a form with multiple select options using the first as indication to continue.

Meaning, if the first isn't selected, you can't select the underneath options (which is set to disabled by default), only when the previous is selected you can select the next than next and so on.

I have my code almost done, but can't revert all to disable when I change the first option to it's initial status which is the `value=""` .

Also I could only figure out how to use `onblur` instead of an instant enable.

Including a fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/Ljozz9mx/

```js
document.getElementById("ReservationCreationList").onblur = function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").value = "";
  }
}

/* I had to split this into a seperate function, because i did not know how to include this in the previous */
document.getElementById("example-date-input").onblur = function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 2em;">



  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="example-time-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Select Restaurant</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <select class="form-control" id="ReservationCreationList" name="NameReservationCreationList" onChange="getRestaurant(this.value);">
      <option name="" value="">Select Restaurant</option>
      <option name="ReservationFormSelector1" value="Restaurant1">Apollo</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Reservation Date</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="date" value="" id="example-date-input" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="example-time-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Reservation Time</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <select class="form-control" id="ReservationTimeList" name="NameReservationTimeList" onChange="getTime(this.value);" disabled>
      <option value="">Select Time</option>
      <option value="1900">1900</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle as it really helps in debugging the issue

Comment: There is a code snippet you can run, can't you see the details?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ljozz9mx/

Comment: Running your code snippets is giving error. I have posted my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jquery chunk will meet all your requirements.

```
$("#ReservationCreationList").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#example-date-input, #ReservationTimeList").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#example-date-input").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});

$("#example-date-input").on('change', function() {
    $("#ReservationTimeList").prop("disabled", $(this).val() === "");
})
```

Comment: This is doing what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to you.. Please check the below code.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3o7pcu2a/

```
document.getElementById("ReservationCreationList").onblur = function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("example-date-input").value = "";
    document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").value = "";
  }
}


document.getElementById("example-date-input").onblur = function() {
   if (this.value.length > 0) {
     document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").disabled = false;
   } else {
   document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("ReservationTimeList").value = "";
  }
}
```